# How to find Jenkins build jobs consuming high CPU and Memory

Tags: performance, jenkins, cpu

So far, Our Jenkins service hanging everyday, we cannot access the web page, I have to restart Jenkins services after hanging.

In Jenkins, I only set 4 of executors. Sometime, when 4 build job are running, the CPU load almost 90%, I guess that is a reason why Jenkins dies.

So how can I find which build job consume high CPU, and how can I find a root cause why the Jenkins die, I check in system log, but did not find any useful info.
I'm running Jenkins version 2.150.1 in Ubuntu 16.04.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We were also facing same issues..  We did setup prometheus + graphana monitoring for Jenkins..

This video is helpful - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3H9eNIf9KZs

With this - we able to point the timing when CPU was hitting at its peak and then we able to findout the job causing CPU consumption.  We have switched to ECS(AWS Cloud) based job runnings.. i.e CPU and memory is separately allocated to each job..

We have also added jenkins observer script on machine where Jenkins is hoasted. we have checked if jenkins is down i.e if giving 502, we restarted it using crontab script.

These things helped us to solve the problems related to jenkins downtime.